# Does ASP.NET MVC, or any other modern web development framework provide ONE single web development environment?

Tags: php, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, web

I keep searching for this online with no answer. I understand that web development you worry about the front end (HTML, CSS, javascript) and the backend (PHP, JSP, ASP.NET, etc). All of these use different languages, technology, development environment. My question then is do ASP.NET MVC provide a single IDE (visual studio) and one language/syntax to worry about (C#)? If so, is there an open source comparison to this? If not, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using proprietary technology from microsoft (ie. licenses, expenses)?

---

So if there is no single language even when using a framework, is it just one IDE (like visual studio)? is that an advantage in itself? Do you have the same for PHP Cake and other frameworks?

Comment: even Microsoft has multiple languages...C#, F#, Visual Basic, C++. As for IDE's use what whatever you like, most of the good ones have plugins for almost everything.

Comment: If you're asking if there's one IDE that can handle all these different languages: yes, plenty, and Visual Studio specifically. If you're asking if there's something that will let you write *everything* (JavaScript, CSS, etc.) all in C#, then no, no such thing exists.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC uses C#, html.
It is pelasure to work in MVC 4. There a lot of books and I start to read Jon Galloway:).

Answer (score 1):

There is not one language for front end and back end.  With a language like PHP or C#/VB.net you have the language that gets parsed by the server (PHP/C#/VB) and a language(s)/markup that gets parsed by the client's browser (Javacript/jquery/HTML/CSS).  And, you can mix the two (ie: server can parse HTML, etc).  All OO IDE's support their specific back end code + all client code.  As new technologies become available, most IDE's will build in support (ie, for jquery).  There is an open source for .Net (http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) but i've never used it.  Microsoft does offer a free version of its .Net Studio (search express edition)